# How to automate Powershell's interactive Get-Credential method?

Tags: linux, python, powershell

I am trying to write a python script which automates the powershell's Get-Credential method. Here is something i wrote:

```
import subprocess
COMMAND_LINE = 'powershell'
powershell = subprocess.Popen(COMMAND_LINE, shell=True,
                                   stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = powershell.stdout.readline()
print output.rstrip()
powershell.stdin.write('$cred = Get-Credential\n')
powershell.stdin.write('Administrator\n')
powershell.stdin.write('Password')
output = powershell.stdout.readline()
print output.rstrip()
out = powershell.communicate()[0]
print(out)
```

But i am unable to pass the password as above, i am getting following exception:

```
> PS /root> $cred = Get-Credential
> 
> Windows PowerShell credential request Enter your credentials. User:
> Administrator Password for user Administrator: PS /root>
> PasswordPassword : The term 'Password' is not recognized as the name
> of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
> spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
> is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
> + Password
> + ~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Password:String) [], CommandNot    FoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

As i am new to python, Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 5):

Your python problem is the `\n` after the commands, `write` already append a newline, so your script does the following:

```
$cred = Get-Credential # Start the command
# This line is ignored as extraneous after Get-Credential, but you can see it in your output.
Administrator # Send proprely to the User: prompt
# Sent to the Password: prompt
Password # Send to the shell input, causing the error at end of your log.
```

Now that's a quite hard way to automate the credential object in powershell, usually the object is build by other way like described in [this blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gary/2009/07/23/creating-a-ps-credential-from-a-clear-text-password-in-powershell/) (quoting here for completeness):

```
$password = "mypassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "nwtraders\administrator" 
$credential = New-ObjectSystem.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
```

And used as such:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName Server1 -Credential $credential
```

Answer (score 3):

I am by no means an expert but there is an alternative to creating a script containing 'plain text' passwords, which obviously isn't very secure.

I have written the following code snippet based on this article [Who Are You? Or, Slipping By the Get-Credential Cmdlet](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2011/09/06/powershell-get-credential-cmdlet.aspx) by [Jeff Hicks](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JefferyHicks) and now use this in order to automate a remote session.

```
# Create a secure string for the password
$Username = Read-Host "Enter Username"
$Password = Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString

# Create the PSCredential object
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username,$Password)

# Server Variable
$Server = Read-Host "Enter Server Name"

# Create Remote Session
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $Server -Credential $Credentials
```

When running this code, you will get the following output:-

```
PS Scripts:\> .\Snippets\Enter-SecureCreds.ps1
Enter Username: ##YOUR-USERNAME#
Enter Password: *************
Enter Server Name: 192.168.1.10
```

Password is obfuscated with * when entered.

As advised in Jeff's article

> This credential only exists for as long as your PowerShell session is
>   open. But be careful, because even though the password is stored as a
>   secure string, if I have interactive access to the console session, I
>   can still see the password by invoking the GetNetworkCredential()
>   method:

```
PS S:\> $Credential.GetNetworkCredential()

UserName          Password          Domain
--------          --------          ------ 
admin             P@ssw0rd          mydomain
```

> This isn't necessarily a security violation, unless you walk away and
>   leave your session wide open for anyone to access. There may also be
>   situations where you have a legacy application that can't use a
>   PSCredential and you need to pass values like username and password to
>   it. Just be aware.
>
> IMPORTANT: It is a security no-no to hard-code any password in any
>   plain text file. Ideally, you'll want to provide some secure mechanism
>   for the script user to provide the necessary password. Also, don't
>   forget to secure your console if you are keeping the credential
>   object.

I hope you find this as useful as I have.